# How to optimize sorting program in Python?

Tags: python, sorting

I need to write a program that takes a list of strings containing integers and words and returns a sorted version of the list. The output should maintain the positions of strings and numbers as they appeared in the original string.

```
data=raw_input("Enter data").split(" ")
alpha=[]
num=[]
for item in data:
if item.isalpha():
    alpha.append(item)
else:
    num.append(item)
alpha.sort()
num.sort()

i=0
j=0
result=""
for item in data :
  if item.isalpha():
    result +=alpha[i]+" "
    i +=1
  else:
    result +=num[j]+" "
    j +=1

print result
```

Above code is working fine for me, but I want to use minimum memory. **How can I reduce the above code and get the correct result with a single list and least iteration?**

**input**

> car truck 8 4 bus 6 1

**output**

> bus car 1 4 truck 6 8

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. It says the program takes a list of strings, but your sample input is a string, not a list.

Comment: data=raw_input("Enter data").split(" ") this line returns a list object.

Comment: @JulienBernu: upon re-reading, you are correct, reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't avoid having to sort twice, or create *some kind of mapping* for the number positions here. Either partition, sort the partitions, and re-assemble based on the types in the original word list (as you did), or resort a sorted word list based on a type position map.

To create a type position map, you record 'type' positions first (where the difference is determined using `str.digit()`). You can then sort all words regardless of type, then *re*sort based on the type map:

```
type_map = {}
words = line.split()
for i, word in enumerate(words):
    type_map.setdefault(word.isdigit(), []).append(i)

# sort keys
# sort digits as numbers (natural sort)
int_for_digits = lambda w: int(w) if w.isdigit() else w
# sort specific types to the next position for that type 
type_to_pos = lambda w, m={k: iter(v) for k, v in type_map.items()}: next(m[w.isdigit()])

sorted_line = sorted(sorted(words, key=int_for_digits), key=type_to_pos)
```

Note that the `type_to_pos` lambda creates a map from 'type' (`str.isdigit()` outcome) to position *iterators*, and these are going to be exhausted after sorting. Make sure you create the lambda anew each time you need to sort the same line.

I also incorporated a natural sort to ensure that `10` is sorted after `9`, not before as a lexicographical sort on strings would do.

Demo:

```
>>> line = 'car truck 8 4 bus 6 1'
>>> type_map = {}
>>> words = line.split()
>>> for i, word in enumerate(words):
...     type_map.setdefault(word.isdigit(), []).append(i)
...
>>> int_for_digits = lambda w: int(w) if w.isdigit() else w
>>> type_to_pos = lambda w, m={k: iter(v) for k, v in type_map.items()}: next(m[w.isdigit()])
>>> sorted(sorted(words, key=int_for_digits), key=type_to_pos)
['bus', 'car', '1', '4', 'truck', '6', '8']
```

There is no real difference in memory use between this and yours; both solutions require creating some additional lists (with a total length equal that of number of words).

Answer (score 2):

This Python 2 / Python 3 code uses a similar algorithm to yours, but it avoids the retesting of data types when building the result string.

It creates a list `dtypes` that stores the datatypes of the items as references to the destination lists `alpha` and `num`. This simplifies the process of putting the sorted items back into the correct sequence.

We use reversed sorts so that we can `.pop()` the desired items off the ends of their lists. This is more efficient than using `.pop(0)`, since popping items from the front of a list requires all the subsequent items to be moved down every time we pop.

```
from __future__ import print_function

def parallel_sort(data):
    ''' sort numeric & non-numeric items in str `data` in parallel,
        keeping numeric values in the original numeric slots
        and alpha values in the original alpha slots
    '''
    data = data.split()
    alpha = []
    num = []
    dtypes = [num if item.isdigit() else alpha for item in data]
    for lst, item in zip(dtypes, data):
        lst.append(item)

    alpha.sort(reverse=True)
    num.sort(key=int, reverse=True)
    return ' '.join([lst.pop() for lst in dtypes])

# Test

strings = (
    'car truck 8 4 bus 6 1',
    '9 2 car bus 297',
    'dog ape 1 12 333 emu cat 7 32 zebra bat',
)

for data in strings:
    result = parallel_sort(data)
    print('{!r} -> {!r}'.format(data, result))
```

**output**

```
'car truck 8 4 bus 6 1' -> 'bus car 1 4 truck 6 8'
'9 2 car bus 297' -> '2 9 bus car 297'
'dog ape 1 12 333 emu cat 7 32 zebra bat' -> 'ape bat 1 7 12 cat dog 32 333 emu zebra'
```

---

Here's some `timeit` code to compare the speeds of the various algorithms. For small strings, piyush's code (modified to sort numbers correctly) is the fastest, but for sufficiently large strings my code is a little faster.

These tests were performed on an old 2GHz Pentium 4 machine running Python 2.6 (I had to modify Martijn's code because 2,6 doesn't have dictionary comprehensions).

```
from __future__ import print_function
from timeit import Timer

def parallel_sort_piyush(data):
    data = data.split()
    alpha=[]
    num=[]
    for item in data:
        if item.isalpha():
            alpha.append(item)
        else:
            num.append(item)
    alpha.sort()
    num.sort(key=int)

    i = 0
    j = 0
    result = ""
    for item in data :
        if item.isalpha():
            result += alpha[i] + " "
            i +=1
        else:
            result += num[j] + " "
            j +=1
    return result[:-1]

def parallel_sort_acw1668(data):
    data = data.split()
    alphas = sorted([x for x in data if x.isalpha()])
    numbers = sorted([x for x in data if not x.isalpha()], key=int)
    return ' '.join(alphas.pop(0) if x.isalpha() else numbers.pop(0) for x in data)

def parallel_sort_martijn(line):
    type_map = {}
    words = line.split()
    for i, word in enumerate(words):
        type_map.setdefault(word.isdigit(), []).append(i)

    # sort keys
    # sort digits as numbers (natural sort)
    int_for_digits = lambda w: int(w) if w.isdigit() else w
    # sort specific types to the next position for that type 
    #type_to_pos = lambda w, m={k: iter(v) for k, v in type_map.items()}: next(m[w.isdigit()])
    type_to_pos = lambda w, m=dict((k, iter(v)) for k, v in type_map.items()): next(m[w.isdigit()])
    return ' '.join(sorted(sorted(words, key=int_for_digits), key=type_to_pos))

def parallel_sort_PM2R(data):
    ''' sort numeric & non-numeric items in str `data` in parallel,
        keeping numeric values in the original numeric slots
        and alpha values in the original alpha slots
    '''
    data = data.split()
    alpha = []
    num = []
    dtypes = [num if item.isdigit() else alpha for item in data]
    for lst, item in zip(dtypes, data):
        lst.append(item)

    alpha.sort(reverse=True)
    num.sort(key=int, reverse=True)
    return ' '.join([lst.pop() for lst in dtypes])

funcs = (
    parallel_sort_piyush,
    parallel_sort_acw1668,
    parallel_sort_martijn,
    parallel_sort_PM2R,
)

strings = (
    'car truck 8 4 bus 6 1',
    '9 2 car bus 297',
    'dog ape 1 12 333 emu cat 7 32 zebra bat',
    'only alpha words',
    '42 23 17 5',
    '',
)

def test():
    for parallel_sort in funcs:
        print(parallel_sort.__name__)
        for data in strings:
            result = parallel_sort(data)
            print('{0!r} -> {1!r}'.format(data, result)) 
        print()

def verify():
    for data in strings:
        result = [parallel_sort(data) for parallel_sort in funcs]
        r = result[0]
        ok = all(s == r for s in result[1:])
        print('{0}: {1!r} -> {2!r}'.format(ok, data, r))

# Time tests

def time_test(loops, reps):
    ''' Print timing stats for all the functions '''
    timings = []
    for func in funcs:
        fname = func.__name__
        setup = 'from __main__ import datastring, ' + fname
        cmd = fname + '(datastring)'
        t = Timer(cmd, setup)
        result = t.repeat(reps, loops)
        result.sort()
        timings.append((result, fname))

    timings.sort()
    for result, fname in timings:
        print('{0:21} {1}'.format(fname, result))

#test()
verify()

reps = 3
loops = 5000
for datastring in strings:
    print('\n{0!r}'.format(datastring))
    time_test(loops, reps)

print('\n' + '- ' * 32)

datastring = ' '.join(strings * 3)
reps = 3
loops = 256
for i in range(7):
    print('\nlength={0}, loops{1}'.format(len(datastring), loops))
    time_test(loops, reps)
    loops >>= 1
    datastring += datastring
```

**output**

```
True: 'car truck 8 4 bus 6 1' -> 'bus car 1 4 truck 6 8'
True: '9 2 car bus 297' -> '2 9 bus car 297'
True: 'dog ape 1 12 333 emu cat 7 32 zebra bat' -> 'ape bat 1 7 12 cat dog 32 333 emu zebra'
True: 'only alpha words' -> 'alpha only words'
True: '42 23 17 5' -> '5 17 23 42'
True: '' -> ''

'car truck 8 4 bus 6 1'
parallel_sort_piyush  [0.16613292694091797, 0.1678168773651123, 0.17213606834411621]
parallel_sort_PM2R    [0.19424915313720703, 0.19544506072998047, 0.1982269287109375]
parallel_sort_acw1668 [0.26951003074645996, 0.27229499816894531, 0.2791450023651123]
parallel_sort_martijn [0.38483405113220215, 0.39478588104248047, 0.41512084007263184]

'9 2 car bus 297'
parallel_sort_piyush  [0.12851309776306152, 0.1293489933013916, 0.13681578636169434]
parallel_sort_PM2R    [0.16056299209594727, 0.16071605682373047, 0.16141486167907715]
parallel_sort_acw1668 [0.22338008880615234, 0.22396492958068848, 0.22573399543762207]
parallel_sort_martijn [0.31512093544006348, 0.31612205505371094, 0.3207099437713623]

'dog ape 1 12 333 emu cat 7 32 zebra bat'
parallel_sort_piyush  [0.22555994987487793, 0.22738313674926758, 0.2362220287322998]
parallel_sort_PM2R    [0.2644810676574707, 0.26884698867797852, 0.30507016181945801]
parallel_sort_acw1668 [0.34023594856262207, 0.3423771858215332, 0.34470510482788086]
parallel_sort_martijn [0.49398708343505859, 0.49546003341674805, 0.50142598152160645]

'only alpha words'
parallel_sort_piyush  [0.069504022598266602, 0.06974482536315918, 0.077678918838500977]
parallel_sort_PM2R    [0.097023963928222656, 0.10160112380981445, 0.10884809494018555]
parallel_sort_acw1668 [0.16136789321899414, 0.16139507293701172, 0.16254186630249023]
parallel_sort_martijn [0.20757603645324707, 0.20803117752075195, 0.21358394622802734]

'42 23 17 5'
parallel_sort_piyush  [0.12735700607299805, 0.13022804260253906, 0.13068699836730957]
parallel_sort_PM2R    [0.14782595634460449, 0.14879608154296875, 0.14986395835876465]
parallel_sort_acw1668 [0.2091820240020752, 0.21131205558776855, 0.21974492073059082]
parallel_sort_martijn [0.27461814880371094, 0.27850794792175293, 0.27975988388061523]

''
parallel_sort_piyush  [0.024302959442138672, 0.024441957473754883, 0.031994104385375977]
parallel_sort_PM2R    [0.046028852462768555, 0.046576023101806641, 0.046601057052612305]
parallel_sort_acw1668 [0.091669082641601562, 0.091941118240356445, 0.092013120651245117]
parallel_sort_martijn [0.094310998916625977, 0.094748973846435547, 0.095381021499633789]

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

length=320, loops256
parallel_sort_PM2R    [0.086880922317504883, 0.087455987930297852, 0.087592840194702148]
parallel_sort_piyush  [0.089211940765380859, 0.089900970458984375, 0.10294389724731445]
parallel_sort_acw1668 [0.1074371337890625, 0.10886883735656738, 0.11089897155761719]
parallel_sort_martijn [0.15668392181396484, 0.15747618675231934, 0.15912413597106934]

length=640, loops128
parallel_sort_PM2R    [0.086150884628295898, 0.088001012802124023, 0.091377019882202148]
parallel_sort_piyush  [0.088989019393920898, 0.089003086090087891, 0.095314979553222656]
parallel_sort_acw1668 [0.10632085800170898, 0.10663104057312012, 0.10766291618347168]
parallel_sort_martijn [0.15318799018859863, 0.1544189453125, 0.1579129695892334]

length=1280, loops64
parallel_sort_PM2R    [0.086312055587768555, 0.08635711669921875, 0.08643794059753418]
parallel_sort_piyush  [0.089561939239501953, 0.089729070663452148, 0.09730219841003418]
parallel_sort_acw1668 [0.10796380043029785, 0.10807299613952637, 0.10920286178588867]
parallel_sort_martijn [0.15214014053344727, 0.15265083312988281, 0.1530609130859375]

length=2560, loops32
parallel_sort_PM2R    [0.086397886276245117, 0.086937904357910156, 0.12731385231018066]
parallel_sort_piyush  [0.090615034103393555, 0.091663837432861328, 0.1024620532989502]
parallel_sort_acw1668 [0.11186099052429199, 0.113922119140625, 0.11545681953430176]
parallel_sort_martijn [0.1525418758392334, 0.15349197387695312, 0.15409398078918457]

length=5120, loops16
parallel_sort_PM2R    [0.086872100830078125, 0.089444875717163086, 0.092289924621582031]
parallel_sort_piyush  [0.09121394157409668, 0.092126131057739258, 0.099750041961669922]
parallel_sort_acw1668 [0.11780095100402832, 0.11782479286193848, 0.11829781532287598]
parallel_sort_martijn [0.1548459529876709, 0.1556861400604248, 0.16153383255004883]

length=10240, loops8
parallel_sort_PM2R    [0.087334871292114258, 0.091704845428466797, 0.092611074447631836]
parallel_sort_piyush  [0.092457056045532227, 0.11381292343139648, 0.11914896965026855]
parallel_sort_acw1668 [0.13423800468444824, 0.14225006103515625, 0.14964199066162109]
parallel_sort_martijn [0.15410614013671875, 0.15437102317810059, 0.15663385391235352]

length=20480, loops4
parallel_sort_PM2R    [0.089828014373779297, 0.089951992034912109, 0.091377973556518555]
parallel_sort_piyush  [0.093550920486450195, 0.093831062316894531, 0.10358881950378418]
parallel_sort_martijn [0.15582108497619629, 0.15685820579528809, 0.15839505195617676]
parallel_sort_acw1668 [0.15901684761047363, 0.15937495231628418, 0.16479396820068359]
```

And here's the `timeit` output running on Python 3.6; I couldn't run Martijn's code because it uses a Python 2 feature which is not supported on Python 3 (the ability to compare strings & integers).

```
'car truck 8 4 bus 6 1'
parallel_sort_piyush  [0.1639411759988434, 0.1641379140000936, 0.16782489100114617]
parallel_sort_PM2R    [0.19857631000013498, 0.20035489499969117, 0.20133615400118288]
parallel_sort_acw1668 [0.23366880700086767, 0.23590722699918842, 0.23592727899995225]

'9 2 car bus 297'
parallel_sort_piyush  [0.13465033200009202, 0.13776905200029432, 0.18482623500131012]
parallel_sort_PM2R    [0.17675577999943926, 0.17687105299955874, 0.17699695900046208]
parallel_sort_acw1668 [0.1984550399993168, 0.2004171780008619, 0.20442987299975357]

'dog ape 1 12 333 emu cat 7 32 zebra bat'
parallel_sort_piyush  [0.23316595300093468, 0.23489147600048454, 0.23842128900105308]
parallel_sort_PM2R    [0.26679581300049904, 0.3011208970001462, 0.3172619519991713]
parallel_sort_acw1668 [0.3200034309993498, 0.3352665239999624, 0.33631655700082774]

'only alpha words'
parallel_sort_piyush  [0.09549654300099064, 0.09623185599957651, 0.10429198799829464]
parallel_sort_PM2R    [0.13186385899825837, 0.13212396900053136, 0.13451194299886993]
parallel_sort_acw1668 [0.1535412909997831, 0.1543631849999656, 0.15927939099856303]

'42 23 17 5'
parallel_sort_piyush  [0.11825022300035926, 0.11878074699961871, 0.1252167599996028]
parallel_sort_PM2R    [0.1604483920000348, 0.16769106699939584, 0.1691959849995328]
parallel_sort_acw1668 [0.18632163399888668, 0.1896887399998377, 0.1903514539990283]

''
parallel_sort_piyush  [0.02776817599988135, 0.028196225999636226, 0.03495696800018777]
parallel_sort_PM2R    [0.08110263499838766, 0.08155031299975235, 0.08626208599889651]
parallel_sort_acw1668 [0.0864310500001011, 0.09174712499952875, 0.09336608200101182]

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

length=320, loops256
parallel_sort_PM2R    [0.07467737899969507, 0.0790010450000409, 0.08554027799982578]
parallel_sort_piyush  [0.08288037499914935, 0.0869976689991745, 0.08999215999938315]
parallel_sort_acw1668 [0.09541546199943696, 0.09584146999986842, 0.10051055599979009]

length=640, loops128
parallel_sort_PM2R    [0.07285131699973135, 0.07332802500059188, 0.0734102949991211]
parallel_sort_piyush  [0.08446464299959189, 0.08626877000097011, 0.0912491470007808]
parallel_sort_acw1668 [0.09565138899961312, 0.09577698600151052, 0.1005053829994722]

length=1280, loops64
parallel_sort_PM2R    [0.0734182439991855, 0.07344354999986535, 0.07376041499992425]
parallel_sort_piyush  [0.08504722700126877, 0.08517580999978236, 0.09426504600014596]
parallel_sort_acw1668 [0.09750029599854315, 0.09771097199882206, 0.098332843001117]

length=2560, loops32
parallel_sort_PM2R    [0.0732510199995886, 0.07328447399959259, 0.0746706619993347]
parallel_sort_piyush  [0.08774417499989795, 0.08785101400098938, 0.09428778500114277]
parallel_sort_acw1668 [0.10173674399993615, 0.103946167999311, 0.11013430999992124]

length=5120, loops16
parallel_sort_PM2R    [0.07310179399974004, 0.07344265099891345, 0.07423899999957939]
parallel_sort_piyush  [0.08817732100033027, 0.0979379299988068, 0.10110497500136262]
parallel_sort_acw1668 [0.10930270000062592, 0.11099402399850078, 0.11111589400024968]

length=10240, loops8
parallel_sort_PM2R    [0.0742019289991731, 0.0743915310013108, 0.08267202100068971]
parallel_sort_piyush  [0.0880410829995526, 0.08827138900051068, 0.09606961099962064]
parallel_sort_acw1668 [0.12271693899856473, 0.1237988149987359, 0.1242337999992742]

length=20480, loops4
parallel_sort_PM2R    [0.07891896799992537, 0.08560944000055315, 0.09119457000088005]
parallel_sort_piyush  [0.08942042499984382, 0.0914211269991938, 0.0983720500007621]
parallel_sort_acw1668 [0.15465029900042282, 0.17178430700005265, 0.1722458230015036]
```

Comment: This is basically the partitioning approach the OP is using; put words in one list or another based on `str.isdigit()`.

Comment: Avoiding retesting is indeed something you want to point out. :-)

Comment: Also, you could add an explicit explanation as to what `dtypes` does: record type positions by storing references to the two partition lists. That's a neat trick here.

Comment: I'm looking for more optimize code in my code i have used 3 list and 2 loops , i want to reduce code to single list and one loop

Comment: Thanks, @MartijnPieters !

Comment: @piyushsingh: you can't. I already covered this in my answer.

Comment: @piyushsingh: Sure, my code uses 3 lists & 2 loops like yours, but it does half the number of tests, and it avoids the index arithmetic, so it _is_ a little more efficient. I don't see a simple way to do it with a single loop & a single list, but if such an algorithm exists it would certainly be _very_ difficult to read, and readability is generally more important than trivial differences in execution speed.

Comment: @piyushsingh: I've added some code to my answer that tests the speed of the various algorithms.

Comment: @piyushsingh: What do you mean? Your original code doesn't do a numeric sort on the numbers, and it appends an extra space to the result string, but once those two issues are fixed your code works correctly, and it's quite fast. Mine is only faster than yours if the input string is large, but even then the difference isn't huge.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = raw_input("Enter data:\n").split()
alphas = sorted([x for x in data if x.isalpha()])
numbers = sorted([x for x in data if not x.isalpha()], key=int)
output = ' '.join(alphas.pop(0) if x.isalpha() else numbers.pop(0) for x in data)
print(output)
```

Comment: instead of input use raw_input and after executing i got incorrect output.  input:  9 2 car bus 297
output: 2 297 bus car 9

Comment: @piyushsingh: that's because this answer doesn't use natural sorting. You could add a `key=int` to the `numbers = sorted([..])` call.

Comment: @martijnPieters your code is working but i'm looking for a logical answer

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Code-only answers are discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

I reduced code to a single list.

```
 def inplace_sort(input_string):

 int_index, output_string, input_string_list = 0,"",[]

      for item in input_string.split(' '):
   if item.isdigit():
    input_string_list.append(int(item))
   else:
    input_string_list.append(item)

    input_string_list = sorted(input_string_list)

 for alpha_index, value in enumerate(input_string_list):
   if isinstance(value, str):
    break

 for item in input_string.split():
   if item.isdigit():
    output_string += str(input_string_list[int_index]) + " "
    int_index += 1
else:
    output_string += input_string_list[alpha_index] + " "
    alpha_index += 1

  return "\nOutput:\n"+output_string

     if __name__ == "__main__":
     output_string = inplace_sort(raw_input("\nInput:\n"))
      print output_string
```